# how do I get user photo from firestore?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

how do I get user photo from firestore?

when I use real-time DB, I using this ways.

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(firebaseUser.getUid());
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot datasnapshot) {
                UserModel userModel = datasnapshot.getValue(UserModel.class);
                uid_photo = userModel.getUserimage();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
```

But if wanna change to use firestore, how do I get values?

I tried to use

```
db.collection("Users").document(firebaseUser.getUid()).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = task.getResult();
                    String userimage = documentSnapshot.getString("userimage");
                    uid_photo = userimage;
                }
            }
        });
```

but I get null value.

so how could I did?

Comment: "but I get null value" - where, exactly? Does your document definitely have a `userimage` field? (And are you sure you want to store an image as a string? I'd expect bytes to be more suitable...)

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Please also respond with @AlexMamo